# Do XPath on a Node with Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have someNode and I'd like to do XPath on it like this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//name");
Object result = expr.evaluate(SOMETHING_ELSE, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

How can I turn someNode to SOMETHING_ELSE and do my XPath?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Elaborate

Comment: I think maybe you're misunderstanding the use of evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with `Object result = expr.evaluate(someNode, XPathConstants.NODE);`? The XPathExpression takes an Object as first parameter, and you can pass any reference to a node, element or attribute of your XML document.